# Referencing Scheduled TimerTasks of Timer

Tags: java, javafx, timer, timertask

How do I access the TimerTasks scheduled by my Timer? I am trying to cancel a task after deleting the task from my taskMap. I've already tried canceling my Timer which cancels all scheduled task and then I just have to start the Timer again with the updated tasks in my taskMap, but I am getting an "IllegalStateException Timer already cancelled." Here is the code for the class extending TimerTask :

```
public class ShowTask extends TimerTask {

    private static Timer timer = new Timer();
    private static String taskDescription;
    private static Stage popupStage;

    public void run() {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Popup_Controller.taskDesc = taskDescription;
                    popupStage = new Stage();
                    popupStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
                    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/popupTask.fxml"));
                    Scene scene = new Scene(root,295,121);
                    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
                    popupStage.setScene(scene);
                    popupStage.show();
                    Rectangle2D primScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
                    popupStage.setX(primScreenBounds.getWidth() - (popupStage.getWidth() + 10));
                    popupStage.setY(primScreenBounds.getHeight() - (popupStage.getHeight() + 10)); 
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void runTask(String desc, int hour, int min) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        long oneDay = 1000L * 60L * 60L * 24L;
        Date timeExec = cal.getTime();
        taskDescription = desc;
        if (timeExec.before(new Date())) {
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, +1);
            timer.schedule(new ShowTask(), cal.getTime(), oneDay);
            Controller_main.taskMap.put(desc, timeExec);
        } else {
            timer.schedule(new ShowTask(), cal.getTime(), oneDay);
            Controller_main.taskMap.put(desc, timeExec);
        }
        System.out.println(timeExec);
        System.out.println(Controller_main.taskMap.entrySet());
    }

    public static void runTask(String desc, Date date) {
        long oneDay = 1000L * 60L * 60L * 24L;
        taskDescription = desc;
        if (date.before(new Date())) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(date);
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, +1);
            timer.schedule(new ShowTask(), cal.getTime(), oneDay);
        } else {
            timer.schedule(new ShowTask(), date, oneDay);
        }
    }

    public static Timer returnTimer() {
        return timer;
    }

    public static Stage returnStage() {
        return popupStage;
    }
}
```

Comment: "I am trying to cancel a task after I deleting the task from my taskMap" - why you cant first cancel a task then delete it from taskMap?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get what you're trying to say. I have a function called populateList() which reads data from the taskMap and populates the List, at the same time public static void runTask() is called to schedule the task. What I was trying to do was delete the task from my list which deletes it from the taskMap, and then I update the scheduled tasks by calling timer.cancel() to get rid of all schedule task. After which I call popluateList() again which reads from the updated taskMap (this time the deleted task is gone) and then call runTask() again for timer to schedule the updatedtasks